# how can I access to one of the values of one of the objects in an Array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of objects and I want to show all value in each object:

```
var array = [{obj1:{property1:"value1",property2:"value2",property3:"value3"}},
          {obj2:{property1:"value1",property2:"value2",property3:"value3"}},
          {obj3:{property1:"value1",property2:"value2",property3:"value3"}}];
```

When I try something like this I only get to show the key but not the value

```
for (let i in array){
    for (let key1 in array[i]) {
```

Any help?

Comment: You can use: `array[i][key1]`, E.g. `for (let i in array){
    for (let key1 in array[i]) { console.log('value is ' + array[i][key1]); } }`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Object.values()` returns an array of values of the Object passed to it.

You can then use `flatMap` twice to flatten the nested object array and fetch all the values.

```js
var array = [{
    obj1: {
      property1: "value1",
      property2: "value2",
      property3: "value3"
    }
  },
  {
    obj2: {
      property1: "value1",
      property2: "value2",
      property3: "value3"
    }
  },
  {
    obj3: {
      property1: "value1",
      property2: "value2",
      property3: "value3"
    }
  }
];

function getAllValues(array) {
  return array.flatMap(o => Object.values(o))
              .flatMap(o => Object.values(o))
}
console.log(getAllValues(array));
```